# asp.net Unit Test: Mark test as incomplete

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'd like to unit test a asp.net MVC webapplication.
We're not using TDD (well, not yet).

After touching a method I'd like to mark the appropriate unit test as incomplete or something so the other team members know they have to complete it.

Is there any possibility to do so?

We're using the built in Unit test possibility in Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks in advance.
Michael

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the tests to not actually be run until they've been worked on further? If so, there's an `[Ignore]` attribute that you can add to each test, as in (for MSTest):

```
[TestMethod, Ignore]
public void TestThatNeedsToBeCompleted()
{
}
```

If you're using NUnit, you can add a reason parameter to the Ignore attribute to explain why the test is being ignored. I don't think that's available in MSTest, but don't quote me on that :)

Comment: Thank you. We're not using NUnit. Well, I just want the test so others know they have to implement it. Is there any chance to do so?

Comment: You can create the test method and set the Ignore attribute - it should get picked up in the test runner

Answer (score 2):

You can simply fail the test with assertion or throw `NotImplementedException`. And you will see that these tests are not ok.

Or eventually use the [IgnoreAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.ignoreattribute%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to [enable/disable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182457%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#UsingIgnoreAttribute) the test when you need.

```
[Ignore]
[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod { }
```

Comment: I think it's too much work to manually throw an exception somewhere in the unit test.
Is there really no attribut for marking a test as uncompleted?

I thought about Ignore and basically after putting it above my test method the test for this method didn't run. But it wasn't shown somewhere that this test didn't run.

Comment: How do you define uncompleted? A test that is not set to Ignored either goes green if it passes or red if it doesn't. If you want to highlight to your developers that they need to do some work on the test and you don't care about failing tests, write some code that will automatically cause the test to fail. The simplest way to do that is via the `NotImplementedException` attribute. Is it really too much work to add `throw new NotImplementedException();` to the body of your unit test?